# devstack installation with swift enabled

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon

I tried the default installation(s3 installed), but when I try to use swift (via the python client), it give me this `Endpoint for object-store not found` error for all commands:

```
source admin-openrc.sh 
swift --debug --os-region-name "RegionOne" post test_container test_obj.txt
ERROR:swiftclient:Endpoint for object-store not found - have you specified a region?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1184, in _retry
    self.url, self.token = self.get_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1158, in get_auth
    insecure=self.insecure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 345, in get_auth
    insecure=insecure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 293, in get_keystoneclient_2_0
    'have you specified a region?' % service_type)
ClientException: Endpoint for object-store not found - have you specified a region?
Endpoint for object-store not found - have you specified a region?
```

So it looks like that swift is not installed/enabled. But I couldn't figure out the correct `localrc` configuration for devstack.

Currently it is:

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD=some_password
RABBIT_PASSWORD=some_password
SERVICE_TOKEN=some_password
SERVICE_PASSWORD=some_password
ADMIN_PASSWORD=some_password

ENABLED_SERVICES+=,swift
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
```

I have tried various combinations, devstack just wouldn't install correctly.

Basically I'd like to keep all default services (horizon, api etc.), and enable swift.
Other options I have tried:

```
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service neutron 

enable_service swift s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
```

I also feel `unstack.sh` is not cleaning up properly, which adds more headache for me to try different configuration.

The `stack.sh` script always end up giving me errors like those:

```
++ glance --os-auth-token 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-eG5rJNzHC45MRnDZtkyKHz456tuWSXAKanrKpEKcspHkb4zzMEJiIveHa9f9aF628n0jVUvp4ePg67AXj6Gyf3E4QgCKMd49kNtAO9MenO0mF97cigb1-1go2DClqJiw3tubhjvD8YyKhGUFXt+Ji-dq60G9-SbTA0pUcgbjSJcrY5rHm78MNcnugpp7qGqyLWJ8KNWK+o4vXT-CH-9lhsyBjAezXzY++mJT-imFgIvTb3evNetNlbohqf1qQh76vPQzXB-e6LiJHMaxtnNf882y56Xs4fxZhC6e3rFdEx2K0BD3XbDlDCrrns2O0vXMRipA= --os-image-url http://115.146.86.242:9292 image-create --name cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec-kernel --is-public True --container-format aki --disk-format aki
500 Internal Server Error
Failed to upload image e3c70c20-ef7b-4704-b74a-922e9f52239d
    (HTTP 500)
+ KERNEL_ID=
+ '[' -n /home/ubuntu/devstack/files/images/cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec/cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-initrd ']'
++ get_field 2
++ grep ' id '
++ read data
++ glance --os-auth-token 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-eG5rJNzHC45MRnDZtkyKHz456tuWSXAKanrKpEKcspHkb4zzMEJiIveHa9f9aF628n0jVUvp4ePg67AXj6Gyf3E4QgCKMd49kNtAO9MenO0mF97cigb1-1go2DClqJiw3tubhjvD8YyKhGUFXt+Ji-dq60G9-SbTA0pUcgbjSJcrY5rHm78MNcnugpp7qGqyLWJ8KNWK+o4vXT-CH-9lhsyBjAezXzY++mJT-imFgIvTb3evNetNlbohqf1qQh76vPQzXB-e6LiJHMaxtnNf882y56Xs4fxZhC6e3rFdEx2K0BD3XbDlDCrrns2O0vXMRipA= --os-image-url http://115.146.86.242:9292 image-create --name cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec-ramdisk --is-public True --container-format ari --disk-format ari
500 Internal Server Error
Failed to upload image 2c7e2905-97ef-4cfc-98af-24b03372db9d
    (HTTP 500)
+ RAMDISK_ID=
+ glance --os-auth-token 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-eG5rJNzHC45MRnDZtkyKHz456tuWSXAKanrKpEKcspHkb4zzMEJiIveHa9f9aF628n0jVUvp4ePg67AXj6Gyf3E4QgCKMd49kNtAO9MenO0mF97cigb1-1go2DClqJiw3tubhjvD8YyKhGUFXt+Ji-dq60G9-SbTA0pUcgbjSJcrY5rHm78MNcnugpp7qGqyLWJ8KNWK+o4vXT-CH-9lhsyBjAezXzY++mJT-imFgIvTb3evNetNlbohqf1qQh76vPQzXB-e6LiJHMaxtnNf882y56Xs4fxZhC6e3rFdEx2K0BD3XbDlDCrrns2O0vXMRipA= --os-image-url http://115.146.86.242:9292 image-create --name cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec --is-public True --container-format ami --disk-format ami
500 Internal Server Error
Failed to upload image 5d4d3c86-05cc-4ad4-9d24-09eb1bf24146
    (HTTP 500)
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ exit 1
```

Should I try something like install swift on a correctly installed default devstack environment? It seems there is more work if using this method. Found some examples below (not complete):

```
keystone service-create --name swift --type object-store --description "Swift Storage Service"
keystone endpoint-create --service_id SERVICEID --publicurl "http://IP:8080/v1/AUTH_\$(tenant_id)s" --adminurl "http://IP:8080/v1" --internalurl "http://IP:8080/v1/AUTH_\$(tenant_id)s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.phymata.com/2013/12/18/devstack-havana-on-the-rackspace-cloud/

Those steps proposed by Everett Toews

+

With the updated localrc https://gist.github.com/chandankumar1/8181381 by Chandan Kumar.

I finally manage to get it to work (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 4GB RAM).

Comment: That gist is no longer available... This previously worked for me, but alas no more: ENABLED_SERVICES+=,s-proxy,s-object,s-container,s-account

Answer (score 0):

Simple try using

enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account

no need for explicitly writing swift, I've mine working now.